# Was Tenser the Dungeons & Dragons character named after the song from Bester's The Demolished Man?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, games, the-demolished-man

One of the original characters in E. Gary Gygax's *Greyhawk* Dungeons & Dragons campaign was Tenser, created by Gygax's son Ernie.  The name is an anagram of "Ernest," which was the legal first name of both Ernie and Gary.  It is possible that Ernie may have come up with the name himself, but I have sometimes wondered whether the name might have been influenced by the earworm song from Alfred Bester's 1953 novel *The Demolished Man*.

> Her fingers and palm slipped gracefully over the panel.  A tune of utter monotony filled the room with agonizing, unforgettable banality.  It was the quintessence of every melodic cliché Reich had ever heard.  No matter what melody you tried to remember, it invariably led down the path of familiarity to "Tenser, Said The Tensor."  Then Duffy began to sing:
>
> *Eight, sir; seven, sir;
>
> Six, sir; five, sir;
>
> Four, sir; three, sir;
>
> Two, sir; one!
>
> Tenser, said the Tensor.
>
> Tenser, said the Tensor.
>
> Tension, apprehension,
>
> And dissension have begun.*

Ernie probably hadn't read Bester's novel, but there is a fair chance that his father had.  (Although *The Demolished Man* was not listed among the inspirations for Dungeons & Dragons in appendix N of the first-edition Advanced Dungeons & Dragons *Dungeonmaster's Guide*, that's not really germane, since it is very clearly science fiction rather than fantasy.)  And "Tenser, said the Tensor," may well be the most famous quote Bester ever produced.

So, did anyone from the original circle of D&D players ever comment on the name—whether it was just a coincidence or not?

Comment: I'd argue that "In brightest day, in blackest night, no evil shall escape my sight[...]" is more famous :)